# How can I copy text from a tmux window to the system clipboard?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, tmux

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with tmux 2.1. Mostly I split the screen in two tmux windows split vertically. Frequently, I need to copy long pieces of text from the tmux window and paste it in the sublime text/browser. I have a feeling that xsel/xclip could be used to achieve the same. However, most of the how-to's floating in the Internet are severely bloated, trying to explain intricate configuration option without really explaining:

- What exactly do I need to configure in `tmux.conf`?
- How do I select a piece of text in the tmux window?
- How do I copy the selected piece of text?
- How do I paste the text from system clipboard to text editor/browser?

I don't want to be a tmux guru. All I want to get the job done in simplest possible way. Any clue how to do that?

Comment: really excellent article on all things tmux copy paste ubuntu, pretty much written for this question: https://www.rushiagr.com/blog/2016/06/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting-ubuntu/

Comment: May refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255031/how-to-copy-from-tmux-running-in-putty-to-windows-clipboard

Answer (score 7):

I personally am using Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL2 . However this solution will work on Ubuntu 16.04 also.
I have been using `tmux-yank` for copything text from tmux buffer to system clipboard.
You would first need to set up `Tmux Plugin Manager`. Follow [this](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm) link.

Then set add `tmux-yank` plugin to your `.tmux.conf` file , see [here](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-yank).

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looking at the example configurations at: /usr/share/doc/tmux/examples$

You can also look at the current key bindings using ctrl+b+?.

You can change these default key bindings in the .tmux.conf file.
It depends on your settings how you select a piece of text in tmux window. You can map the key bindings as per vim. Enter the copy mode (ctrl+b + [), scroll to the start/end of the text you want to copy to the tmux clipboard, press v (provided the key bindings as per vim) to start copying. move to the other end of the text, press y to yank the text. press ctrl+b+] to paste the text.

I am trying to figure out how to copy/paste from system clipboard on this version. Will update my answer if I have any luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just realized that I mis-pressed it to ctrl+b+{.

Answer (score 0):

Searching `tmux copy clipboard` this question was shown and I'd like to share one of the ways how to deal with the problem if you're using `tmux` within `VSCode`. I use selection with the mouse with `set -g mouse on` setting in `.tmux.conf`; to get the selected fragment which is stored in tmux buffer I do `cat | code -` and paste in the running `cat` with `Ctrl-b + ]`; pasted fragment occurs in `VSCode` editor too, then it's easy to copy from the window.

Answer (score -5):

On tmux 1.8 running in ssh session under Putty 0.73 on Windows, below works for me.

**COPY:** Use ctrl+b,] got to start line, press Spacebar (it will start selection and highlighting text), use arrow or PageUp to go to end line, press Enter to get all selected text in buffer.

**PASTE:** ctrl+b,]

Comment: This answers copying and pasting within `tmux`. OP is looking for a way to copy to system clipboard for use elsewhere.