# how to disable the scroll function when I use the tmux?

Tags: tmux

Tmux uses the scroll to find the history commands which bothers me too much.
How to disable this function? I have tried to use "set mouse on", but it gives me another problem. I just want to disable my mouse all the time, with the scroll leaves its original usage.

Answer (score 5):

Tmux no longer has multiple options for mouse mode, there is just `mouse` on or off (assuming a recent version of tmux).

If you want to use the mouse, including the scroll wheel, for anything except scrolling history, mouse mode must be on (`set -g mouse on`). Turning on the mouse should not prevent you from not using your mouse to accomplish things; the default tmux key functionality remains.

Comment: in fact, I'm using mintty in windows. If I turn on the mouse in tmux.conf, the copy and  paste function looks like being disabled. I want to use right click and copy the text I choose, but it doesn't work. How to fix the problem like this?

Comment: does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19996484/5889131) work for you? I've never used mintty. If it does not, this question stops remotely resembling a StackOverflow question and should be submitted on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: No, it doesn't. Actually, I learn that I have to set "set -g mouse on" to scroll up and down. Besides, If I copy and paste from the screen buffer, I have to press the SHIFT key to finish the work, which bothers me a lot.

Comment: This does not work with iTerm.